# Need a Logic to say Bingo

Tags: iphone

I am creating an iphone app where I have a grid view of 25 images as:

0   1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24

Now when  any 5 consecutive images are selected it should say bingo, like if 0,6, 12, 18, 24 are selected it should say Bingo.

How will i do that, please help me.

Many Thanks for your help.

Rs
iPhone Developer

Comment: Why would the sequence "0,6, 12, 18, 24" be "consecutive"? Those numbers are all over the place in the list of 25 images you gave. Would "0,6, 12, 18, 24" be displayed consecutively to the user?

Comment: You posted the same question about a week ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836823/need-a-logic-for-bingo Stop posting duplicates. If no one answered it last time, it's likely to meet the same fate. It's too vague.

Comment: @TheBigO I think those numbers refer to cells that are layered left-to-right, then top-to-bottom; or vice versa.  They would form a diagonal across a grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
-----------------------------------
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |  4  |  5  |
-----------------------------------
| 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  |  10 |  11 |
-----------------------------------
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |  16 |  17 |
-----------------------------------
| 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |  22 |  23 |
-----------------------------------
| 24 |
-----------------------------------
```

Hope this is how your grid looks like.

Associate each column with an array. The array will contain the list of all neighbour elements of that column,

For example, the neighbor array of the column [ 6 ] will ollk like array(0, 7, 12), which are all the immediate neighbors of [ 6 ].

1. Set counter = 0;
2. Now, when someone clicks an element, increment the counter (Now counter = 1)
3. When he clicks the second element, check if the element is in the neighbor list of the previous element OR the 1st element.
   If the element clicked is in the neighbor list, increment the counter (now counter = 2)
   ELSE
   If the element clicked is not in the neighbor array, reset the counter (counter = 0) and start over.
4. Check if the value of counter = 5. If it is, Say Bingo!

The algorithm is not fully correct, but I hope you got the idea :)

Comment: Many Thanks for your help but still I am stuck up, yes its a grid view of 25 images in 5*5 matrix, 5 rows 5 column as you shown, but I am not able to create the logic for bingo, still trying, will let you know if got something, anyways thanks again

Comment: its done now, I have set a flag for each image and when an image is selected, I am setting that flag true and wherever I get 5 consecutive flags true i m showing Bingo.